# Show the last user in the modal

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need help with this code. It is a website that shows users on the screen and the button on the right should open the user information details in a modal. I can't get the information of the user I click on, to appear in the modal. Show me the last one.

**web photo**
[Foto of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHvJh.png)

[Foto of the modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXQXu.png)

**And this is my code**

```
import { Modal } from "antd";
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { userApi } from "../api/userApi";
import { Usuario } from "../interfaces/fetchAllUserResponse";



export const List = () => {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState<Usuario[]>([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  
  

  useEffect(() => {
    // call API
    userApi.get<Usuario[]>('/default/techJobMission')
        .then( resp => {
            setUsers( resp.data );
        })
        .catch( console.log )
  
  }, []);

  const filteredUsers = (): Usuario[] => {

    return users.slice(currentPage, currentPage + 6);

  }

  const nextUser = () => {
    setCurrentPage( currentPage + 5 )
  }

  const prevUser = () => {
    if( currentPage > 0 ){
       setCurrentPage( currentPage - 5 )
    };
  }


  const renderItem = ({ _id, firstName, lastName, ticket, present }: Usuario) => {
  

    const openModal = () => {
      
      setIsModalOpen(true)
    
    }

    const handleOk = () => {
      setIsModalOpen(false);
    };
  
    const handleCancel = () => {
      setIsModalOpen(false);
    };

    return (
      

      <tr key={ _id }>
           
            <td >
                {( present ? <img className="ticket" src="icons/ticket-green.svg"/> : <img className="ticket" src="icons/ticket-red.svg"/>)}
            </td>
           
            <td className="user">
                 <p className="encabezado">{firstName } {lastName}</p>
                 {( present ? <p className="estado">Ha entrado</p> : <p className="estado">No ha entrado</p> )}
            </td>
            
            <td className="id-user">
                <p className="encabezado2">ID</p>
                <p className="estado">{_id}</p>
            </td>
            
            <td className="ticket-td">
                 <p className="encabezado2">Nº de ticket</p>
                 <p className="estado">{ticket + 1}</p>
            </td>
            
            <td>
                 <button onClick={openModal} className="btn-modal"> <img src="icons/menu-modal.svg"/> </button> 
                 <Modal open={isModalOpen} onOk={handleOk} onCancel={handleCancel} >
                    <p>{firstName}</p> 
                  </Modal>

            </td>
               
          </tr>


    )

  }

  
  return (
    <>
    
    <table className="table">

      <tbody>
        {
          filteredUsers().map( renderItem )
        }  
      </tbody>
      
    </table>        
 

    
    <br />
    
    <button onClick={ prevUser } className="paginacion">
        <img src="icons/anterior.svg"/> Anterior
    </button>
    
    <button onClick={ nextUser } className="paginacion">
        Siguiente <img src="icons/siguiente.svg"/> 
    </button>

    

    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's opening *all* of the modals.

You have *multiple* modals and *one* boolean value indicating if "the modal" is open or not.  So either they're all open or they're all not open.

Instead of tracking a single boolean value, track something like an identifier for *which* modal to display.  For example:

```
const [modalID, setModalID] = useState();
```

And:

```
const openModal = (id) => {
  setModalID(id)
}

const handleCancel = () => {
  setModalID(undefined);
};
```

Then pass that `id` to the function from your record:

```
onClick={() => openModal(_id)}
```

And use it to determine if the modal is open:

```
open={modalID === _id}
```

Comment: Thanks David, but I get several errors because I'm in TypeScript...

Comment: and with the handleOk function what do I do?

Comment: @AgustinMarinPosadas: "Because I'm in TypeScript" isn't an error.  What error(s) are you getting?  Are they related to the question being asked or are they a separate issue?

Comment: @AgustinMarinPosadas: How does the `handleOk` function differ from the `handleCancel` function?  Why do you need two functions which do exactly the same thing?

Comment: - The first error is when I assign (id) to the openModal function: "The parameter 'id' has a type 'any' implicitly.ts(7006)"

Comment: And the second error is in the open={() => openModal(_id)}: "Type '() => void' cannot be assigned to type 'boolean | undefined'.ts(2322)
Modal.d.ts(11, 5): The expected type comes from the "open" property, which is declared here in the "IntrinsicAttributes & ModalProps" type

Comment: @AgustinMarinPosadas: `_id` comes from the `Usario` type.  Where do you define that type?  You can also specify a type when declaring the state value, just like you do for `users`.

Comment: @AgustinMarinPosadas: `open={() => openModal(_id)}` - This code isn't in any of the code shown, so I can't really tell you what it's doing or why it's an error.  There's no guarantee that *other code* in your project won't produce an error.  The scope of the answer is only the scope of the question being asked.

Comment: Sorry, the second error comes from open={openModal === _id}: This condition will always return "false", because the types "(id: any) => void" and "string" do not overlap.

Comment: And Usuario comes from an Interface that I have made in a separate file like this:


export interface Usuario {
    _id:string;
    ticket: number;
    present: boolean;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    birthday: string;
    email:string;
    phone:string;
    address: string;
}

Comment: @AgustinMarinPosadas: Oh, I see the problem.  When I re-named the state value I accidentally used a name that was also being used as a function below.  I've updated the answer to rename the state value to `modalID` instead.

Comment: Could you upload how all the code would look in general by editing the one I've uploaded? Thanks, David

Comment: @AgustinMarinPosadas: You are misunderstanding what Stack Overflow does.  The purpose of this answer is to help you understand the solve the problem, not to provide you with production-ready code that you can copy/paste without understanding the problem. In this case the underlying logical problem was that you were trying to use a single boolean value to determine multiple conditions. The solution is to replace that single boolean value with something more flexible. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.